# Compilation failing

Tags: java, interface, compiler-errors

This is a snippet of Java code:

```
interface Rideable {
    String getGait();
}

public class Camel implements Rideable {
    int x = 2;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Camel().go(8);
    }

    void go(int speed) {
        System.out.println((++speed * x++) + this.getGait());
    }

    String getGait() {
        return " mph, lope";
    }
}
```

It turns out that compilation fails (according to Oracle) though in my opinion it shall run fine producing output. So, where is the culprit for failing compilation?
Cheers

Comment: Please copy-paste the compiler diagnostic.

Comment: I did not compile it. It comes from Oracle certification page. Just a drill and I am trying to identify the flaws just by looking at a pure code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't reduce the visibility of methods you override (interface methods are `public` by default), try this instead:

```
public String getGait() {
    return " mph, lope";
}
```

Comment: Wow, that is great identification!

Answer (score 2):

You have defined `getGait` with default access but interface definitions are require their implementations to be `public`.

```
public String getGait() {
```